# 3d transform for a parent-child divs

Tags: css, css-transforms

Why for the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="face"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    transform: perspective(900px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: rot 8s infinite linear;
}
.bottom {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 15%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.face {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: rotateY(60deg);
}
```

A blue square doesn't cover the red rectangle when it turns back (`backface-visibility` doesn't help)? At the same time when `.bottom` and `.face` are not in a parent-child relationship everything works as expected.

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PIalqZzv7UvaC9e66UGx?p=preview)

Note: works in Chrome. In Firefox the first example doesn't work. In IE both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the CSS propertis inherit.

transform-style is an exception

setting

```
.bottom {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

or

```
.bottom {
    transform-style: inherit;
}
```

will solve the problem

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/k2ElF7vu1QlT63G4QEfK?p=preview)